# Extracting html element from string

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I have some XML string output which looks like the following:

```
<xml>
<node>
<Title name="Title">Tea and Coffee</Title>
<Menu-Item name="Menu-Item">
<div class="field-item field-item-0">Freshly brewed fairtrade filter coffee and a selection of fairtrade tea and herbal infusions</div><div class="field-item field-item-1">Ut laoreet porta tellus, ut pellentesque ipsum dictum metus.</div>
</Menu-Item>
</node>
</xml>
```

The next thing I need to do is extracting the 'div' elements and casting them so I can use them as jquery objects as normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know you do not use regex! That I know

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Do you not know how to select anything from xml? do you not know how to convert the xml node you are getting into a jquery object? You might want to clarify exactly where you've got to and where you are stuck...

Comment: Are you calling this XML with AJAX? Is the code already on the page? Standard jQuery would be `var div = $('.field-item');`

Comment: Yes I am using ajax to shift through the xml output. I am doing the following <code>$($menuitem).each(
          function(){
           alert('Found : ' + $($menuitem).text() );
          }
         );</code> but I get the content of both 'divs' concatenated into one. I wonder if there is a way to retrieve the content as div elements so I can refer to them as jquery object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us say you have this as a text string in a variable named myxml. Then you read it with jquery, as follows:

```
$(myxml).find('div').each(function() { alert($(this).text()); })
```

The alert is only meant to show how you can get the inner text. Here's a post that can help you with more examples: [reading-xml-with-jquery](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<xml>'+
    '<node>'+
    '<Title name="Title">Tea and Coffee</Title>'+
    '<Menu-Item name="Menu-Item">'+
        '<div class="field-item field-item-0">Freshly brewed fairtrade filter coffee and a selection of fairtrade tea and herbal infusions</div><div class="field-item field-item-1">Ut laoreet porta tellus, ut pellentesque ipsum dictum metus.</div>'+
    '</Menu-Item>'+
    '</node>'+
'</xml>').find('div').appendTo('body');
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/EhQKv/